# Typoscript condition with new symfony expression syntax

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

Anybody here who knows how to write this TS condition in the new symfony expression syntax?
`[globalVar = TSFE:sys_page|versioningWorkspaceId = 1]`

Or is there any other way to find out if one is viewing a workspace?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the desired syntax is:

`[getTSFE().sys_page.versioningWorkspaceId == '1']`

As a rule of thumb, 
Arrays should be written with brackets,
Objects are written with points.